# How to pass cat output as a wget url parameter?

Tags: cron, parameter-passing, wget, cat, piping

I have a small file containing just a number located at /mnt/1wire/342342342/temperature
I need to create a cron to wget http://myserver.com/myurl?temp= (and here goes that line)
I believe I should use somewhat cat /myfile | wget http://myserver.com?parameter= ? 
I don't want to create any temporary files and I want to output the received data from get to null.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
wget http://myserver.com/myurl?temp=`cat /mnt/1wire/342342342/temperature` -o /dev/null -O /dev/null
# -o output log
# -O output document
```